# UIPickerView width issue in iphone 6s and above devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uipickerview

UIPickerview width issues in iphone 6s simulator. works perfectly in iphone 5s and 6 devices but pickerview width doesn't fit in iphone 6s and above devices simulator.

Below is my code and attached screenshot[image: pickerview].TIA

```
- (IBAction)btnFeetClicked:(id)sender {

    date=@"Date";

    selectedpickerview=_DatepickerView;
    CGRect rect;
    rect = [_DatepickerView frame];
    rect.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds)-320;
    rect.size.height = 330;
    _DatepickerView.frame = rect;
    [self.view addSubview:_DatepickerView];
    [_Datepicker reloadAllComponents];

}
```

Comment: Do you mean 6plus? As 6s and 6 both have same width.

Comment: why didn't you set the x???

Answer (score 2):

it will fit to any screen :

**check this :**

```
rect=CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y-self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-self.view.frame.size.width);
```

and remove code hardcoded values

```
rect.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds)-320;
    rect.size.height = 330;
```

Comment: what about orientation change??

Comment: u can go with 'UIInterfaceOrientation' and change the code for width as hight and hight as width....

Answer (score 0):

Why do you set frame of UIPickerView? Here `rect` is same as configured in storyboard/xib. It is better to use auto layout and set appropriate constraints.